# What does those square brackets mean?

Tags: notation, physics, mathematical-physics

While reading an article online, I encountered this expression.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone knows what does the square brackets in this expression do?

Thank you.

Comment: It is only a way of grouping the expression to be evaluated at "point" $s=L$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f:A \to B$ is a function and if $a \in A$ then $[f(x)]_{x=a}$ simply means $f(a)$.

Comment: If that is the case, why couldn't the equation just be written exactly the way it is, except with $s = L$? I mean, it would be much simper for me to write $f(a) = b$ rather than $\left[f(x)\right]_{x=a} = b$.

Comment: Because the above expression involves derivatives. What this notation implies that you need to take the derivative with respect to $s$ before you plug in $s=L$

Comment: But the semantics of the symbol f(x) is tantamount to the content of the brackets, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

What if the bracket is inside an integral? Or with a cipher or varible at the top and bottom see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts. But what else can it mean in calculus? Can it also mean a derivation?

Comment: How does this answer the question?